# How can I monitor how much cache memory is used with Azure role-based caching

Tags: azure

Is there a way to see how much memory is used by Azure Cache (preview)?
It is not quite clear to me what serialization method is used (binary, xml, json?) So it's hard to provision how much memory my cached objects require.
Any insights are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've been told but haven't tried if first hand... that the performance counter "AppFabric Caching:Host\Available Memory Percentage" can give you the amount of cache yet available. In theory, if you're distributing this across role instances, you'd need to aggregate the amount for a total count of the cache size available.

In reality though, you'd only want to do this to see if you're constantly bumping up against the cache limit and want to know you're going to want to increase capacity. The Caching service should handle eviction when utilization grows.

And I believe that the caching serialization is binary, but don't hold me to that. :)